# Twitter-Bootstrap -- Navbar search button appears below search field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Yikes. I've tried everything but can't figure this out. Pretty sure I'm missing something obvious.

I want the search button to appear alongside the search field but, for some reason, it appears below it. What the hell have I missed?

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".main-navbar">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">The Brand Goes Here</a>
</div>

<!-- toggled items -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse main-navbar">
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- end toggled items -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the button that says "submit."  It is currently outside the div element with the text field, so it is on a new line.

Try this:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".main-navbar">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">The Brand Goes Here</a>
</div>

<!-- toggled items -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse main-navbar">
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">submit</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
<!-- end toggled items -->
```

Comment: Whatever you do, you'll have to move the button inside that div.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Tested in Safari and Chrome. I have the button in that div but it makes no difference.

Comment: The fragment in my answer with no other styling works in Chrome.  Could your stylesheet be causing a problem?

Comment: Well problem solved. Wish I could answer the question, but I can't. Recompiling the less files didn't work. Copying and pasting the example from the Bootstrap site didn't work. Going away and having a cup of tea worked. Frustrating!